# abp.ui.setBusy is not implemented

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

When I try to use setBusy on my application, it returns the following error on the console:

WARN:
abp.ui.setBusy is not implemented!

I checked the libs files and both jquery.spin.js and abp.blockUI.js exist in the project. My project is using ABP v.6.0.0.

The order the js files are in the bundle file is as follow:

```
...
"wwwroot/libs/block-ui/jquery.blockUI.js",
"wwwroot/libs/spin/spin.js",
"wwwroot/libs-ext/spin/jquery.spin.js",
...
"wwwroot/libs/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.blockUI.js",
"wwwroot/libs/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.spin.js",
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that should work, you can share the code of your project to help you, check the order in which the libraries are loaded, the call to abp.ui.setBusy requires that it be previously loaded.

```
jquery

...
<script src="~/libs/block-ui/jquery.blockUI.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src="~/libs/spin/spin.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src="~/libs-ext/spin/jquery.spin.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
...
<script src="~/libs/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.blockUI.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I could only get to it again just now. The order in the bundle file is correct. I'll update the post with the order they are in the file.

Comment: Ok, I found the issue. The Layout file was missing /libs-ext/spin/jquery.spin.js for development environment... Including the file solved the problem. Thank you very much!